# php exec() syntax check

Tags: php, cmd, exec

This works in the command prompt(in one line) :

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program && 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\python.exe" unoconv -f pdf d:\class1.doc
```

but when it comes to do the same in PHP's exec() nothing happens - neither message nor any file, probably due to a syntax error :

```
echo exec('cd C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LibreOffice 4\\program &&
"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\LibreOffice 4\\program\\python.exe" unoconv -f pdf d:\\class1.doc');
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have `cd` into a dir, no need to call the executable within it from the full path again. you can call it directly.

Try this:

```
<?php

// Test
$ret = exec('cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\" && python.exe unoconv -f pdf d:\\class1.doc', $output, $error);

// Debug
var_dump($ret);
var_dump($output);
var_dump($error);

?>
```

Take a look at the documentation here: https://www.php.net/function.exec

Comment: the usage of python.exe is fine but still var_dumps empty strings

Comment: var dump of all 3 is empty?

Comment: $ret : string(0) "" 
$output : array(0) { } 
$error : int(1) - cannot see the error ?

Comment: for the purpose of testing, can you copy the `class1.doc` into `C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\` and try this line and see if it works: `$ret = exec('cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 4\program\" && python.exe unoconv -f pdf class1.doc', $output, $error);`

Comment: It should be in another partition the converted document, in C:\ it asks for permissions, even if i have

Comment: Looking at your requirement, you are trying to convert a word doc to a PDF file. Is this an option for you -> https://github.com/mirkonasato/pyodconverter?